# How to check if this function is one to one and onto?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions

I know what is expected, yet I have troubles to calculate or proof it when a rather big matrix is given with numbers and letters.

This is the function I have:

[image]

How can I check if it's one to one? Do I need to check for everything that is in my function T, so let's say `3x-z`, and take a random number for `x` and `z`, and check whether the value that rolls out, is *unique*? I did this, but I don't think this is correct to be honest.

What is the way to approach this? I'd really appreciate some help and tips...

Comment: Do you know how to find the rank of a matrix?  Do you know how to find the dimension of its nullspace?  Do you see how this problem is related to those things?

Comment: Also, what was part a)?

Comment: Part a was about the standard matrix. Does this mean I need the echelon form of the standard matrix?

Comment: that's right, and you could go probably through the steps without ever understanding what they have to do with the problem statement (as many students do). However, part of understanding this question and its answer amounts to understanding the relationship between $T$, its standard matrix, and the echelon form.  So, do you know what I mean by any of that?

Comment: I actually do understand it, but sometimes I just get confused because we need to comprehend A LOT. Okay, so let's say we have rref of the matrix... then what?

Answer (score 1):

T is one-to-one function if the kernel is trivial, so you you neeed to check implication $T(x,y,z)=0\implies x=y=z=0$.

Comment: So, just equations and then checking if I get a zero?

Comment: Yes, it has to be only solution if function is one-to-one.You can read about it [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Linear_Transformation_is_Injective_iff_Kernel_Contains_Only_Zero)

Comment: So... if nullity = 0, we can conlude it's one-to-one, correct? So we get N(T) = 0 which would mean T = one to one.

Comment: @Siyah Note that this statement is a if and only if statement. Either direction works. You might want to prove it to convince yourself that it is true.

Answer (score 0):

Find the REF of the standard matrix (it's not necessary to get to RREF).  Then, look at the pivots (the leading 1's of the rows).

If we have a pivot in every column, then the nullspace of the matrix (and hence the kernel of $T$) is zero-dimensional.  So, $T$ is one-to-one if and only if the REF has pivot in every column.

If we have a pivot in every row, then $T(x,y,z) = \mathbf b$ has a solution for any $\mathbf b$.  That is, the dimension of the image is equal to the dimension of the space.  So, $T$ is onto if and only if the REF has a pivot in every row.

Comment: I get it, but... is this the ONLY way to find it? Because I saw this video, for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MUqHqDWQI9Y where it's done without having to use the matrix. Is this also possible? As you maybe can understand, I am trying to avoid the use of REF as it's very time consuming.

Comment: Honestly, I think REF is the fastest way. Again: you don't need to go all the way to RREF.

Comment: Okay, then what are my other options? @Omnomnomnom

Comment: @Siyah read my answer, i have given you a proof by contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

alans has given you the method for b)

One of the many ways to solve for c) :

Find the range of the linear transformation. i.e. $R(T) = span\{T(1,0,0),T(0,1,0),T(0,0,1)\} = span\{(3,1,1,0),(0,2,-1,1),(-1,0,1,2)\}$

Note: You can use any other basis you like. Also, i would strongly recommend you to prove that the above statement is true in general.

Suppose on the contrary that $R(T)$ is equal to $\mathbb{R}^{4}$.

Then there exist $\lambda_{1},\lambda_{2},\lambda_{3}\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $(0,0,0,1) = \lambda_{1}\cdot (3,1,1,0) + \lambda_{2}\cdot (0,2,-1,1) + \lambda_{3}\cdot (-1,0,1,2)$

Now, this system of linear equation gives you no solution, which is a contradiction.

Note: Suppose you are given another example which $T$ is indeed onto, then you will also find $R(T)$ and show that it is equal to the vector space that $T$ is mapped to.

Comment: Except this $T$ fails to be onto

Comment: @Omnomnomnom right i thought OP wants the method to show a linear transformation is onto. I have edited my answer.